# How do I pick the right CSI camera module?

Tags: camera, csi

I'm looking for a camera module that supports CSI for general photography, so I need reasonable resolution and overall quality. However I can't find any comparisons and there are dozens of modules to choose from. How do I pick the best one?

Comment: You might want to explain what CSI is, provide a few links and maybe a photo, etc.

Comment: MIPI CSI is pretty closed and compatible ISPs or MCUs are difficult to buy for a private person. The parallel camera interface of the STM32 microcontrollers is far easier to understand and implement.

Comment: Every Raspberry Pi Camera uses CSI, so I wouldn't say they are hard to get a hold of.

Answer (score 2):

MIPI CSI bus cameras  require diff. pair routing lanes, and the hardware that can receive the signal. The bandwidth of your receiving hardware is a limiting factor. Of course all normal camera specs come into play. Things to consider include whether this is for a hobbyists toy or production product. There are tons of trade-offs to consider. If this is a hobby, perhaps going with something more hobbyist friendly is recommendable.